# Scale line is not affected by css color of ol-scale-line class

Tags: openlayers, css

I try to change the color of the text inside the scaleline created with Openlayers via `new ol.control.ScaleLine`. To change the color I refer to the scaleline in my css sheet the following way:

```
.ol-scale-line {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
bottom: 0.25em;
left: 88%;
color: red;
background: black;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1.5px solid #703841ff;
}
```

Every other attribute I change works as expected, except the color. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `div` with `ol-scale-line` class, scale control has another `div` with `ol-scale-line-inner` class. This class styles text and left, right and bottom border of scale.

Default values of this class are:

```
.ol-scale-line-inner {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-top: none;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  will-change: contents, width
}
```

So to change color of the scale text, you define style:

```
.ol-scale-line-inner {
  color: red;
}
```

*Remark*: It greatly helps if you know how to use browser debugger. Explanation above is result of inspecting scale control HTML element with browser debugger.

Comment: Thanks, that did it and helped a lot! I started working with the browser debugger, but I will get further into it, thanks for your advice!